# Trouble refactoring current types(possibly GADT/Type Families related)

Tags: haskell, types, refactoring, gadt

I've got types like this:

```
-- There are codes
newtype ICode = ICode { fromICode :: String }
newtype RCode = RCode { fromRCode :: String }
data DCode = DCode1 | DCode2 | DCode3

-- There are locations described by type and code.
-- Current implementation looks like this:
data Location = LocType1 ICode
              | LocType2 ICode
              | LocType3 RCode
              | LocType4 DCode
```

I'd like to refactor these types to address some problems, which are present in current implementation.

It's real easy to demonstrate the properties I'm after with QuickCheck `Arbitrary` and Aeson's `FromJSON` instances and one other function.
First 3 properties are needed to generate correct test data and 4th to
implement business logic.

I'd like to be able to:

1. make Arbitrary instances of all code types such as

   ```
       instance Arbitrary ICode where
         arbitrary = ...
       -- same with RCode and DCode
   ```
2. make `Arbitrary` instances of types like `Location1 ICode`(It clearly differs from current implementation and it's what I'm trying to fix), which describe exact combination of location type and code type. `Location1 ICode` can contain only a subset of `ICode` possible values, so I have to make sure of that.
3. make `FromJSON` instances of all possible types, something in the lines of:

   ```
   instance FromJSON (Location a) where
     parseJSON = ...
   ```

   It's needed to deserialize some json objects depending on their values.
4. Some functions have to work only on one location type. It's pretty inconvenient in current implementation, because I have to use either incomplete functions or not really correct return types such as `Maybe`. I'd like to be able to do something like:

   ```
   location1IncludedInArbitraryLocation :: LocType1 -> Location a -> Bool
   location1IncludedInArbitraryLocation l = ...
   ```

I believe solution lies somewhere in the GADTs/Data Families territory, but I'm not really fluent with this kind of type-fu. If several ways to resolve this issue are possible, which one would be easier to typecheck/work with later?

Comment: Have you tried *phantom types* to partition `ICode` etc?

Comment: @phadej I've thought about it, but haven't tried it yet. It seems that phantom types will help with arbitrary instances, but won't help with property number 4.

Comment: For 4. I'd suggest to make own type `newtype LocTypeOne = LocTypeOne ICode` and `LocType1 LocTypeOne` inside `LocType` ADT. Then add `LocTypeOne -> LocType` "explicit coercion" function and you are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 and 4 seem incompatible.  This sounds like a "fallback" mechanism: use this instance if no more specific instance is available.  You can get this with OverlappingInstances, but I always seem to run into trouble with it.  Worth a shot, I guess.

As for the rest of your problem, it seems like you want `Location` to be a GADT.

```
data LocType = Type1 | Type2 | Type3 | Type4

data Location :: LocType -> * where
    LocType1 :: ICode -> Location Type1
    LocType2 :: ICode -> Location Type2
    LocType3 :: RCode -> Location Type3
    LocType4 :: DCode -> Location Type4
```

Then you can easily do:

```
location1IncludedInArbitraryLocation :: Location Type1 -> Location t -> Bool
location1IncludedInArbitraryLocation (LocType1 icode) l = ...
```

No other cases need be defined here because no other constructor will be well-typed.

I hope this gives you enough to start playing with.

(Needs `DataKinds`, `KindSignatures`, `GADTs`)

Comment: I get your reasoning and maybe 3 have to go(i'm still interested if it's possible to make all of the properties stated above hold). :) I'm a little frustrated with a different aspect. It seems like `LocType` have to be encoded somewhat different to make this code work the way it's supposed to. It's a starting point though.

Comment: Ah, nevermind the second part. I thought for some reason that `LocType` is a type to be used instead of "Code"-types. I think it finally make sense for me.

Comment: @dredozubov, I just realized that #3 asks about FromJSON, rather than Arbitrary.  In that case this should definitely be possible. The weird thing is that the `a` in the `Location a` that you are reading is supplied by the caller, not the JSON, so that may take some getting used to.  You can use an existential to have the parser supply it.  `data AnyLocation where AnyLocation :: Location a -> AnyLocation`, then define `FromJSON AnyLocation`.

Comment: There are JSON objects like `{'type': 'LocType1', code: 'somecode'} `, which i interpret like this: `parseJSON (Object l) = let locationType = parse (.: "type") l :: Result String in case locationType of ...`, so i wanted to leave it like that.